# pulling continuous data with yfinance

Tags: python, yfinance

Newbie for both python and yfinance, but how do you get all the data in long form, not interrupted by "..." in the middle, as in between the dates 2020-01-08  and 2020-01-25 in the example below? thank you.
(using Spyder)

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages")

import yfinance as yf

data = yf.download("AAPL", start="2020-01-01", end="2021-02-01")

print(data)

[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
                  Open        High  ...   Adj Close     Volume
Date                                ...                       
2020-01-02   74.059998   75.150002  ...   74.333511  135480400

2020-01-03   74.287498   75.144997  ...   73.610840  146322800

2020-01-06   73.447502   74.989998  ...   74.197395  118387200

2020-01-07   74.959999   75.224998  ...   73.848442  108872000

2020-01-08   74.290001   76.110001  ...   75.036385  132079200

               ...         ...  ...         ...        ...
2021-01-25  143.070007  145.089996  ...  142.706757  157611700

2021-01-26  143.600006  144.300003  ...  142.946396   98390600

2021-01-27  143.429993  144.300003  ...  141.848038  140843800

2021-01-28  139.520004  141.990005  ...  136.885452  142621100

2021-01-29  135.830002  136.740005  ...  131.763107  177180600


[272 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: `pd.options.display.max_rows = None;pd.options.display.max_columns = None`With this setting, rows and columns will not be omitted

Answer (score 1):

yfinance returns a `pandas.Dataframe` object. In order to see the full return, please import the pandas package and run the set_option method to increase the maximum number of rows to display. Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
```